# I get internal server error while running next js app with styled component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, styled-components, next.js

I'm using Next.js with styledcomponent, It gets no error in Dev mode. but while running in Build production mode. I get an error. without line number or file name.

I have also opened an issue Github
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5932

> **ERROR**
>
> NODE_ENV=production node server.js
>
> Ready on http://localhost:3000
>   Error: An error occurred. See https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/src/utils/errors.md#1 for more information. Additional arguments: undefined
>       at new StyledComponentsError (/Users/rahulkishan/Documents/React_Mobile_and_web/ReactWebV1/purchaseweb/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:161:58)
>       at constructWithOptions (/Users/rahulkishan/Documents/React_Mobile_and_web/ReactWebV1/purchaseweb/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:2182:13)
>       at styled (/Users/rahulkishan/Documents/React_Mobile_and_web/ReactWebV1/purchaseweb/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:2126:12)
>       at Object. (/Users/rahulkishan/Documents/React_Mobile_and_web/ReactWebV1/purchaseweb/.next/server/static/i2aIDkRZkhvVhtPxvk4BE/pages/index.js:4504:77)

Why it shows this error in Build mode only. Not in dev mode.
We have built a large app.
It is really difficult to find the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error has its path

> static/../pages/index.js

And line number as well

After giving `npm run build`

Nexts js creates a build folder as

```
/.next/server/static
```

Inside that folder you will be able to see the complete production code.